# How to reduce torque of wheelCollider when a collision takes place?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, physics, collision, collider

I've done the following:

```
            if (rec.lY is < 32760 and > 0)
        {
            Accélération =
                direction*Mathf.Log(ValeurAccélération * (32760f - rec.lY) / 32760f + 1,
                    2);

            RoueArrièreDroite.motorTorque += Accélération;
            RoueArrièreGauche.motorTorque += Accélération;
            RoueAvantDroite.motorTorque += Accélération;
            RoueAvantGauche.motorTorque += Accélération;
            

        }
        else if (rec.lY < 0)
        {
            Accélération = direction*Mathf.Log(ValeurAccélération * (-rec.lY + 32760) / 32760f + 1, 2);


            RoueArrièreDroite.motorTorque += Accélération;
            RoueArrièreGauche.motorTorque += Accélération;
            RoueAvantDroite.motorTorque += Accélération;
            RoueAvantGauche.motorTorque += Accélération;
           
        }
```

RoueArrièreDroite, RoueArrièreGauche, RoueAvantDroite and RoueAvantGauche are all wheel colliders.

This code uses the gas input of my Logitech pedals to add torque to the wheels, allowing my car prefab to move forward.

The problem is that when my car collides with another gameObject, the torque on the wheelColliders stays the same, making my car move at the same speed.

Is there a way for my car's speed to decrease when it collides with another object?

Comment: Your code shows that the torque is changing. Even if the torque stays the same, the speed of the car will continue to increase.

Comment: not if there isn't any input by the player

Comment: You should reset the `motorTorque` property to 0 while no input.